Access database in one AWS ligtsail instance in another instance
I have two web applications deployed in two instances of AWS Lightsail. Two different subdomains pointed to these instances by using Cloudflare. Lets say abc.example.com to instance 1 and xyz.example.com to instance2. I need to fetch some data in the instance 1's database to instance 2. How do I connect the database of instance 1 in instance 2?
I have opened the 3306 port in instance 1 like

and also changed the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 as shown in the following picture in instance 1

But this method is not working. Is there any other method?

You should connect to the database using the private IP address of the Lightsail instance. So, if instance 2 has the database and has a private IP address of 10.2.2.2, then establish the connection to 10.2.2.2 on port 3306. Let us know how it goes!

I did the same but getting this error 'Host 'ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server'

I am using mysql, and changed ip binding in mysqld.cnf to 0.0.0.0

Might be relevant: Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server - Stack Overflow

is there any specific reason?

Yes, that linked Question is specifically discussing the error you are currently experiencing. It appears that logging in with an Admin user is only allowed on localhost unless you grant additional permissions.
